# Rsyslog through TLS

Tags: centos, tls, rsyslog

I have been trying to get rsyslog to transmit through TLS with no luck so far.

There seems to be something wrong with my configuration, but I cannot pinpoint it.

this is my server conf file:

```
# rsyslog v5 configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability
$ModLoad imgssapi # provides GSSAPI syslog reception

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 10514
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1 # run driver in TLS-only mode
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode anon # client is NOT authenticated

# make gtls driver the default
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/pki/tls/private/rslserver-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/rslserver-key.pem

# specify senders you permit to access
$AllowedSender TCP, 127.0.0.1, 10.111.1.0/24, *.evoltek.test.com 

#add: define logfiles
## /var/log/secure
$template Auth_log,"/var/log/secure.d/%fromhost%/%$year%-%$month%.secure"
## /var/log/messages
$template Msg_log,"/var/log/secure.d/%fromhost%/%$year%-%$month%.messages"
## /var/log/maillog
$template Mail_log,"/var/log/secure.d/%fromhost%/%$year%-%$month%.maillog"
## /var/log/cron
$template Cron_log,"/var/log/secure.d/%fromhost%/%$year%-%$month%.cron"
## /var/log/spooler
$template Spool_log,"/var/log/secure.d/%fromhost%/%$year%-%$month%.spooler"
## /var/log/boot.log
$template Boot_log,"/var/log/secure.d/%fromhost%/%$year%-%$month%.boot.log"
## emergency messages "*.emerg"
$template Emerg_log,"/var/log/secure.d/%fromhost%/%$year%-%$month%.emerg"

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

#### RULES ####

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                -?Msg_log

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              -?Auth_log

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -?Mail_log

# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  -?Cron_log

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 -?Emerg_log

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          -?Spool_log

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                -?Boot_log
```

And this is my client conf file:

```
# rsyslog v5 configuration file

# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/pki/tls/private/rslclient-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/rslclient-key.pem

$ModLoad imuxsock.so
$ModLoad imklog.so
$ModLoad imtcp


$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon 
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog

# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 *

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

*.* @@10.111.1.151:10514
```

I have created the certificates following this guide : http://kb.kristianreese.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=148

My testing environment does not have FQDNs, so I have left blank the DNs fields and the FQDN ones and I have filled the IP field.

Comment: What OS are you using ? In CentOS/RedHat you also to enable the SSL rsyslog port in SElinux.

Comment: Just noticed it's CentOS:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a working configuration for rsyslog 5.8 (from CentOS repos).

I have installed instead the official rsyslog repos and have got rsyslog 7.6.0 up and running in minutes with this configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Rsyslog 5.8 with Centos 6.9 works for me

**Here is a video tutorial:** 
https://youtu.be/eb9GlhD8XnY

Create the certificates on the CA (certificate authority)

```
sudo mkidr /etc/ssl/rsyslog/   
cd /etc/ssl/rsyslog/
```

Install gnutls-utils

```
sudo yum install -y gnutls-utils
```

Generate CA private key (PROTECT THIS KEY!)

```
sudo certtool --generate-privkey --outfile CA-key.pem
sudo chmod 400 CA-key.pem
```

Generate CA public key

```
sudo certtool --generate-self-signed --load-privkey CA-key.pem --outfile CA.pem

Common name: CA.EXAMPLE.COM
The certificate will expire in (days): 3650
Does the certificate belong to an authority? (Y/N): y
Will the certificate be used to sign other certificates? (Y/N): y
Will the certificate be used to sign CRLs? (y/N): y
```

Create SERVERS private key on the CA (certificate authority)

```
sudo certtool --generate-privkey --outfile SERVER-key.pem --bits 2048
```

Create the certificate request for SERVER

```
sudo certtool --generate-request --load-privkey SERVER-key.pem --outfile SERVER-request.pem 

Common name: SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM
```

Sign SERVER key and allow the key pair to be trusted by the other servers

```
sudo certtool --generate-certificate --load-request SERVER-request.pem --outfile SERVER-cert.pem --load-ca-certificate CA.pem --load-ca-privkey CA-key.pem

The certificate will expire in (days): 1000
Is this a TLS web client certificate? (Y/N): y
Is this also a TLS web server certificate? (y/N): y
Enter a dnsName of the subject of the certificate: SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM
```

Create CLIENT private key on the CA (certificate authority)

```
sudo certtool --generate-privkey --outfile CLIENT-key.pem --bits 2048
```

Create certificate request for CLIENT

```
sudo certtool --generate-request --load-privkey CLIENT-key.pem --outfile CLIENT-request.pem 

Common name: CLIENT.EXAMPLE.ORG
```

Sign CLIENT key and allow the key pair to be trusted by the other servers

```
sudo certtool --generate-certificate --load-request CLIENT-request.pem --outfile CLIENT-cert.pem --load-ca-certificate CA.pem --load-ca-privkey CA-key.pem

The certificate will expire in (days): 1000
Is this a TLS web client certificate? (Y/N): y
Is this also a TLS web server certificate? (y/N): y
Enter a dnsName of the subject of the certificate: CLIENT.EXAMPLE.ORG
```

Delete request keys

```
sudo rm *-request.pem
```

Scp SERVER private/key and the CA.pem to SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM
Copy the certificates with scp or a USB encrypted

```
sudo -u root scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa CA.pem SERVER-* root@172.16.9.30:/etc/ssl/rsyslog/
```

Scp CLIENT private/key and the CA.pem to CLIENT.EXAMPLE.COM

```
sudo -u root scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa CA.pem CLIENT-* root@172.16.9.40:/etc/ssl/rsyslog/
```

Install the gtls driver on SERVER and CLIENT

```
sudo yum install rsyslog-gnutls -y
```

Configure SERVER

```
sudo vi /etc/rsyslog.d/rsyslog-tls.conf

# Add
# Listen for TCP
$ModLoad imtcp
# Set gtls driver
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
# Certs
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/ssl/rsyslog/CA.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/ssl/rsyslog/SERVER-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/ssl/rsyslog/SERVER-key.pem
# Auth mode
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
# Only allow EXAMPLE.COM domain
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverPermittedPeer *.EXAMPLE.COM
# Only use TLS
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1 
# Listen on port 6514
# If you want to use other port configure selinux
$InputTCPServerRun 6514
```

Open port 6514 on your firewall

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 6514 -j ACCEPT

sudo /etc/init.d/iptables reload
```

Restart the rsyslog daemon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

Configure CLIENT

```
sudo vi /etc/rsyslog.d/rsyslog-tls.conf

# Add
# Set gtls driver
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
# Certs
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/ssl/rsyslog/CA.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/ssl/rsyslog/CLIENT-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/ssl/rsyslog/CLIENT-key.pem
# Auth mode
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
# Only send log to SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM host
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM
# Only use TLS
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
# Forward everithing to SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM
# If you use hostnames instead of IP configure DNS or /etc/hosts
*.* @@SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM:6514
```

Restart the rsyslog daemon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

To test on SERVER, run tcpdump and send logs from the CLIENT

```
sudo yum install tcpdump -y
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 tcp port 6514 -X -s 0 -nn
```

Comment: It has probably been backported since then. The original question dates back more than 3 years. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 3):

In CentOS/RedHat you also to enable the SSL rsyslog port in SElinux. Something like 
`semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p tcp 10514` should do the trick.

You can check your current syslog port with
 `sudo semanage port -l| grep syslog`

Also you can try, to run rsyslog in debug mode, to see whats happening:
Stop rsyslog daemon, then

`export RSYSLOG_DEBUGLOG="/path/to/debuglog"`

`export RSYSLOG_DEBUG="Debug"`

now start rsyslog with:

`rsyslogd -dn`

To check if syntax used is valid use:

`rsyslogd -N 1`

Comment: This is a CentOS 6 VE running in OpenVZ. It is only for testing, so I have SElinux removed from the template I use, to avoid headaches

Comment: Have you tried to run rsyslog in debug mode ?